# Excel/OpenOffice spreadsheet template for expected and actual values

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, spreadsheet, simulation, modeling

I would like to create a spreadsheet to generate graphs about cost items (anything with a cost, doesn't matter what) in order to have:

- **expected values**: these would be created using some formulas to simulate future costs.
- **actual values**: these would be put in manually based on actual costs after billing.

At the end of a given time period (weekly, monthly...) the user would "freeze" the `expected value` that was calculated earlier, and add the corresponding `actual value` (and these should never be changed again).

The process would repeat itself for the next time periods while re-using either the same or new calculations for the expected values.

Over time, graphs will show the evolution of and different between the `expected` and `actual` values so as to allow for improvements (are the input values for calculations too optimistic / pessimistic?, were any cost items forgotten or not properly defined?...).

**Can someone point me to a template from which I could create such a spreadsheet?**

Comment: Does [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/12-month-sales-forecast-TC001017514.aspx) work for you? These kinds of things are so particular to your line of business that using a pre-canned template is rarely acceptable, and a proper financial forecasting system is often the best solution, rather than using Excel/OO.

Comment: Thanks. The idea is there but that model is way too static (if I want to add an item I have a lot to update for it to work): I'm gonna continue my quest and will post whatever I find in an answer.

Comment: Most likely anything that is not "way too static" is an information system -- before you start looking at MS Access, maybe investigate *real* financial software first.